# How to pass a string from main to macros ParameterizedTest without using global variable?

Tags: c, unit-testing, c-criterion

I've used the framework [Criterion](https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion) to write unit tests. I need to pass string from main to macros, that executes source code and check the result. I can't use global variable.
Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <criterion/criterion.h>
#include <criterion/parameterized.h>

char* g_path_to_dir; //it doesn't work, because global variable is accessible within the same process 

struct input_data_t {
    const   char* path;
};

ParameterizedTestParameters(ArgsForenforce_perms, input_data_for_enforce_perms) {
    static struct input_data_t params[] = {
"some_data", 
"some_data2" 
};

    size_t nb_params = sizeof (params) / sizeof (struct input_data_t);
    return cr_make_param_array(struct input_data_t, params, nb_params);
}

ParameterizedTest(struct input_data_t *param, ArgsForenforce_perms,
          input_data_for_enforce_perms) {
    printf("pid of process in ParameterizedTest = %d \n", getpid());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("pid of process in main = %d \n", getpid());
    g_path_to_dir = argv[1]; //it doesn't work, because global variable is accessible within the same process 

    struct criterion_test_set *tests = criterion_initialize();
    if (criterion_handle_args(argc, argv, true)) {
        result = !criterion_run_all_tests(tests);
    }

    criterion_finalize(tests);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: When you say macros, are you referring to the pre-processor directives?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862910/unit-testing-methods-created-by-a-macro

Comment: I mean, that my code is executed inside ParameterizedTest. It is not related to your link.

Comment: Why can't you use global variables?

Comment: Where is g_path_to_dir used?  In your example code it is not used.

Comment: @Andreas I can not use a global variable, because global variable is initialized and visible within first process, and when ParameterizedTest is executed in the second process, which has other global variable.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann g_path_to_dir will be used in macros ParameterizedTest. I simplified this example.

Comment: Do you mean to say that g_path_to_dir is used in the implementation of the ParameterizedTest macro that is part of the Criterion framework?

Comment: @DirkHerrmann no, it is my variable. It is not the part of Criterion.

Comment: depending on how criterion works internally maybe the environment variables are inherited, allowing you to use `setenv` and `getenv` for passing data from parent to child process: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17758/exception-of-inheritance-of-environment-variables

Comment: It is a bit surprising that global variables can't be used - I wonder how this should allow to test a SUT that uses global variables with Criterion.  In any case, I suspect that there might also be a better solution for this particular case: The name g_path_to_dir indicates to me that you might be doing something for which better solutions exist.  Without knowing the code it is only a suspicion.  That said, the proposal from Andreas regarding the use of environment variables might be a workable solution.